# how can I move files into corresponding folders

Tags: python, file, move, directory

i have a script that is meant to create a number of folders by finding the first letter of each file then checking the uniqueness of the names then create the folders off of the unique values and name the folders after the unique values and finish by putting the corresponding files into the right folder. my code is

```
import os
from os import listdir
import dircache
import sys
import shutil
import dircache
import glob

path = "C:\\Users\\hra\\Desktop\\fg"
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for fname in dirList:
    print fname

#myList = fname
myList2 = sorted(dirList, key=lambda x:x[0:3])
oldList = [x[0] for x in myList2]
newList = list(set(oldList))
for char in newList:
    print newList

root_path = "C:\\Users\\hra\\Desktop\\fg"
folders = newList
for folder in folders:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))


fCounter = len(glob.glob1("C:\\Users\\hra\\Desktop\\fg","f*"))
mCounter = len(glob.glob1("C:\\Users\\hra\\Desktop\\fg","m*"))
bCounter = len(glob.glob1("C:\\Users\\hra\\Desktop\\fg","b*"))
nLCounter =  len(newList)
```

so far i have managed to get my code to create and rename the desired files from the unique values but i am struggling to move my files into the corresponding folders as it is meant to be able to hand a potentially unlimited number of files which could lead to many unique values being created

Answer (score 1):

add this at the end of your program

```
import os
for fname in dirList:
  os.rename(fname,os.path.join(root_path,fname[0],fname))
```

or you might like to import shutil and use

```
shutil.copyfile(fname, path.join(root_path,fname[0],fname))
```

instead as this is non destructive